# Some of the input fields don't change border colors on input and some do

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const form = document.getElementById('formareg');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const lozinka = document.getElementById('lozinka');
const ime = document.getElementById('ime');
const prezime = document.getElementById('prezime');


form
  .addEventListener(
    'submit',
    (event) => {
      ime.classList.toggle('error', !ime.validity.valid);
      prezime.classList.toggle('error', !prezime.validity.valid);
      email.classList.toggle('error', !email.validity.valid);
      lozinka.classList.toggle('error', !lozinka.validity.valid);

      if (!ime.validity.valid) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      if (!prezime.validity.valid) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }


      if (!email.validity.valid) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      if (!lozinka.validity.valid) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  );

ime
  .addEventListener(
    'input',
    () => {
      ime.classList.toggle('uredu', ime.validity.valid);
    }
  );

prezime
  .addEventListener(
    'input',
    () => {
      prezime.classList.toggle('uredu', prezime.validity.valid);
    }
  );

email
  .addEventListener(
    'input',
    () => {
      email.classList.toggle('uredu', email.validity.valid);
    }
  );

lozinka
  .addEventListener(
    'input',
    () => {
      lozinka.classList.toggle('uredu', lozinka.validity.valid);
    }
  );
```

```css
#ime.uredu {
  border: none;
}

#ime.error {
  border: 2px solid #eb7178;
}

#prezime.uredu {
  border: none;
}

#prezime.error {
  border: 2px solid #eb7178;
}

#lozinka.error {
  border: 2px solid #eb7178;
}

#email.error {
  border: 2px solid #eb7178;
}

#email.uredu {
  border: none;
}

#lozinka.uredu {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="container" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off" id="formareg" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    <h3>Ime*</h3>
    <input type="text" name="ime" id="ime" class="input" placeholder="Ime" required>

    <h3>Prezime*</h3>
    <input type="text" name="prezime" id="prezime" class="input" placeholder="Prezime" required>
  
    <h3>Email*</h3>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input" placeholder="Email" required>
  
    <h3>Lozinka*</h3>
    <input type="password" name="lozinka" id="lozinka" class="input" placeholder="Šifra" required>  
  
    <div class="buttoncontainerreg">
      <button class="button2b" name="button2b" type="submit" onclick="predajKorisnika();">Registruj se</button>
    </div>
  
    <div class="prikazilink" id="prikazilink">
      <a href="prijava.php" class="reroute" id="link">
        <p>Već imaš nalog? Prijavi se<p>
      </a>
    <div>
</form>
```

I've used this code on the login page and for submitting tasks and it works perfectly fine. When the user tries to submit a form without the required fields, it doesn't allow it to submit and makes the borders of the empty fields red. And then when the users starts typing in the empty field, it removes the border.

It works for the `email` and `lozinka` fields here, but for some reason not for `ime` and `prezime`. I thought it might be the text type of the input field, but that also works fine on the form for submitting tasks. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

The issue of some input fields changing border color on input while others don't might be due to different CSS styles applied to each input field.

When we give input. The input field has a CSS style applied that requires a border color change on input, the border color of the input field will alter when the user inputs data into that field. On the other hand, if the CSS style applied to an input field does not contain a border color change on input, the border color of that input field will remain the same regardless of user input.

To fix this problem, you need to identify the CSS styles applied to each input field and confirm that they are consistent. You can also modify the CSS style of the input fields that do not change border colors on input to include a border color change when the user inputs data. This can be done by adding the CSS pseudo-class :focus to the input field selector and specifying the desired border color change in the CSS style rule for the :focus pseudo-class.

Comment: But the CSS styles are consistent, I've included them